# Reading a 3.1 jmx JMeter file with a 3.0 JMeter

Tags: jmeter, version

I have downloaded Apache JMeter 3.1 version and developed a JMX script file. But all my other members use Apache JMeter 3.0 version. I am unable to open my 3.1 jmx file in 3.0 version.
Can anyone suggest how to open the JMX file of 3.1 version in Apache JMeter 3.0 version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Blind shot: my expectation is that you are suffering from [Bug #60252](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60252). Since JMeter 3.1 a new metric `Sent Bytes` has been introduced

> **New Metrics**
>
> A new sent_bytes metric has been introduced which reports the bytes sent to server.
>   Another metric connect_time has been enabled by default in this version

So now [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listeners explicitly rely on this metric. If you have these listeners in test plan - just remove them and you should be able to open the script using JMeter 3.0.

Things to consider:

1. Recommend colleagues upgrading to JMeter 3.1 as newer JMeter versions should normally contain performance improvements and bug fixes
2. Don't add any listeners to your Test Plan. Really. Listeners should be used for tests development and debugging and viewing test results **after** test is finished.

   - Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode like:

     ```
     jmeter -n -t /path/to/script.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
     ```
   - When test is done - open JMeter GUI, add listener(s) of your choice and using "Browse" button locate `results.jtl` file - you will see saved and calculated metrics

   Check out [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) article for more details
3. Raise an issue in [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) recommending listing the aforementioned listeners in the [Incompatible Changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Incompatible%20changes) section
4. Going forward add essential *jmeter.log* file parts to your question for non-telepathic community members

Answer (score 0):

As any good software, JMeter takes a big care (believe us as our team leader is an active member of Dev Team) of backward compatiblity but it cannot consider issues when opening a file saved in version N+1 by software in version N (as with any software I think).

So follow Dmitri advice to make your colleagues upgrade to 3.1 for all the good reasons here:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter-3-1-is-out-with-new-great-features/

But no need to raise a bug (as he recommends) as **it is absolutely not a bug.**